# Creating Customer Document list

Tags: 2013, office-365

I need to create SharePoint site which has a list of customers where my internal users can select the customer and a library with all the relevant documents for that customer come up. I also need to make the default look just a lookup that encompasses all the documents within that site. I also need to filter these so that customers can login and see only their documents. I'm not asking for a how to but if someone can point me in the right direction to get started. I have created a custom list that includes my customers and their numbers but I am having issues

1. Putting it in the quick launch area so people can select from there
2. Creating radio buttons for the list.

I have been looking around the internet for a while now and I haven't come up with anything.

Comment: I would say look at connected web parts. 1 web part will pull the customer information with a selector. It will be connected to a document library webpart which will filter based on the selection in the customer webpart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is is SharePoint online, you can share the site with externals customers and this doesn't need a license to be purchased but it comes with its limitations. You can share the SharePoint site to customer's corporate email address and the customer can login to your site using their corporate email address. To do this there is a one time registration of customer email address with microsoft live. You can read about it here:
[Sharing sites with users outside your organisation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Share-sites-or-documents-with-people-outside-your-organization-80e49744-e30f-44db-8d51-16661b1d4232?ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US)

You can create libraries and add your customers on to them and display the documents using Content Search Webpart, so that when a customer logs in he/she will only see the documents that is shared with them.

For example, if you have a library called "ABC Docs", you would create a SharePoint Group called ABC (customer name) and add users from that customer on to this SharePoint Group. You would then share your ABC docs library with ABC sharePoint group and the customer would only see documents form this library in the Search webpart.

Makes sense?

Comment: That does make sense. I created a search web part and added the customer list into the queries so that each customer is displayed and people can just click on them. The question now is how I link the document libraries to the queries. Any suggestions? @manu

Comment: ok so I created Results Sources for two of the libraries that I will create. Does anyone have suggestions for creating multiple queries so they are listed on the front page in a list where people can just click on and see the document library for that customer?

Comment: You could insert Content Search Webpart on the page where you want to display documents. You can use your result sources or use Path variable in your query to display documents from specific libraries in the Content Search Webparts. This may give you more information: 
https://sharesilver.wordpress.com/2013/10/24/content-search-web-part-for-specific-sharepoint-listlibrary/

You could also use the 'contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary' filter to display only libraries in the search webpart instead of documents.

Comment: Ok that pointed me in the right direction. I used the 'contentclass:STS_List_DocumentLibrary' then used the Path property filter and input the path to my SP sight which displayed all the libraries I created. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you need to take care

1. Supporting customers to login and see their documents - Since this is Online version you should purchase extra user licenses for each customer
2. In the document library you can create separate folder for each customer. Break the inheritance at the folder level. This way you can easily manage effective permissions

For adding links in quick launch, you can edit the site navigation (from site settings) and edit the links.

Comment: ` I also need to filter these so that customers can login and see only their documents.`